# Best Method to Mass Convert WordPress URLs to new URL structure?

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, dns, seo

I have a plan laid out to migrate my 30k+ posts WordPress site to a custom site built by me. One of the main contention points I have is SEO and I'm pretty sure I need to properly forward all of my post URLs if I don't want to decimate my SEO on Google (which is doing extremely well for me).

Current Structure:
https://ygoprodeck.com/xyz-rank-up-shark/

New Structure: https://ygoprodeck.com/deck/xyz-rank-up-shark

This part is easy as I can build the new URLs using the `post_name` column from WordPress in the new Database and simply redirect the old URLs to the new `/deck/` URLs.
However, how can I make the forwarder differentiate between posts and pages?

Take this example:

Current Structure: https://ygoprodeck.com/ritual-summoning-the-underdogs-greatest-hits/

New Structure: https://ygoprodeck.com/article/ritual-summoning-the-underdogs-greatest-hits/

I'm not entirely sure how my forward will know to redirect to `/deck/` or redirect to `/article/` ?

The only solution I can think of is manually redirecting each 30k+ URL which seems like a monumental task to me.

Comment: How do you know which goes to deck and which ot article?
What is the criteria?

Comment: The wordpress post category it is set to would be the criteria

Comment: So what you want to do it to check category and make redirection based on it.
Right?

Comment: Logically that does make sense however I didn't think any type of url forwarder (htaccess/cloudflare) would have that capability

Comment: No
It needs to be done in wordpress php

Comment: Not sure if that will work for me as the intention is to completely remove WordPress with this new custom site (domain will be the same).

Comment: You can write it all to a file with redirect rules. But not by hand but by php script in the same wordpress php. And then use that file in cloudflare or anywhere you want. But yes you're right it that case you'll need a regirection rule for each post. So if you have 30k posts then it will be a file with 30k lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$file = wp_get_upload_dir() . 'rules.txt';
$open = fopen( $file, "a" );

args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$posts = new WP_Query($args);

if( $posts->have_posts() ){
    while( $posts->have_posts() ){
        $posts->the_post();
        global $post;

        $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
        //Assuming each post has only 1 category
        $category =  get_the_category($post->ID)[0]->name;

        $write = fputs( $open, 'Redirect 301 ' . $permalink . ' /' . $category . $permalink. '\n' );
    }
    flocse( $open );
    wp_reset_query();
}
```